# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is not booting after altering a text file in gedit, how to fix?

Tags: boot, graphics, xorg, brightness

After failing to adjust my screen brightness in Ubuntu in various ways, I tried the following guided by an answer in askubuntu.

I opened the following text file

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

It was blank. Then I wrote there the following

```
Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;"
```

saved the file and restarted Ubuntu. But it didn't boot and said:

```
Could not write bytes: Broken Pipe
```

I tried fixing from Ubuntu recovery mode, once again guided by askubuntu answers, but every time it said: wrong commands, and the problem remained. Kindly help with proper commands or with a way to fix it from Windows 8.1 partition of the same machine.

If possible, also guide about adjusting screen brightness.

Answer (score 0):

If it was edited using gedit, It would have made a `xorg.conf~` file.

Delete the `xorg.conf` file and rename the `xorg.conf~` file as `xorg.conf`.

For the brightness problem, do this :

Simply go to /etc/default/grub.cfg as root and find the line which says something like
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= (............) paste these lines into the double quotes :

`quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`

and then run :

`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Changes take place at reboot.

Comment: I have to access the file to rename it, how to access? I have installed diskinternals linux reader in my windows partition, and can view the file from there, but editing seems to be not allowed. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a livecd - the one you used to install ubuntu should be fine. Or download another one in your windows partition, burn it and boot from that.

Mount the filesystem. It will be something like

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

If you can't find it, run

```
dmesg | grep sda
```

to discover the hard disks that have been detected by the kernel, and you can mount one of those. It will likely be sda2 or similar if you have installed windows first, but there may be a partition in front for /boot and swap depending on your partitioning layout. You'll have to follow your nose a bit.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf_old
```

should then reverse the changes you made.

if you have not made any other changes, this should allow you to boot. if you have, then use the livecd to change those back as well.

It's often a good idea to make one change at a time, just in case.
To backup the file concerned, run

```
sudo cp /path/to/file.conf /path/to/file.conf_bak
```

If things go wrong, you can

```
sudo mv /path/to/file.conf_bak /path/to/file.conf
```

to get you back up and running again.